# Throttled state in publishing

Tags: 2011, publishing

I am getting Throttled error while publishing in Tridion 2011 SP1 version.

It is showing Waiting to Publish since long time and then failing as Throttled.

I came to know that we need to edit some content delivery settings to resolve this.

Is it only problem at content delivery side or Content manager settings also.

When I checked the logs I got message as

```
Unable to get the xml of the transport instruction
The item tcm:0-1102531-66560 does not exist.


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Oracle.OracleDatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Read(TcmUri id, StoredProcedureInvocation spInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Read(TcmUri id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetDataObject(TcmUri id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags flags, Boolean forceReload)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishTransaction.get_DeployerAction()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Transporting.TransportEngine.MakeTransportInstruction(TransportPackage transportPackage)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Transporting.TransportEngine.MakeTransportInstruction(TransportPackage transportPackage)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Transporting.TransportEngine.Send(TransportPackage transportPackage)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.SendTransportPackage(TransportPackage package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.HandlePublishRequest(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Handling.DefaultPublishTransactionHandler.ProcessPublishTransaction(PublishTransaction publishTransaction)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()
```

Any solutions to this to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 'Throttled' state means that the Transport Service is unable to move the transport package (a zip file) from the Publishing server (often the same machine as the CM server) to the Deployer server.

This is normally because the Deployer is too busy to handle any more 'Incoming' packages.  We can increase the 'Window size' on the Deployer server, to allow it to accept more incoming packages.

So, in answer to your question, this is often a Content Delivery setting (the 'Window size') that needs to be updated, but the problem shows on the Publisher side (because the Transport server cannot move the file).

The online documentation (login required) has a [If the Publishing Queue shows the item stuck at 'Throttled'](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_AB39F6665A544BB8BB19C5738912E663) page.

There is also a Tridion Knowledge Base article on this here:  [http://tridion.kb.sdl.com/#tab:homeTab:crumb:7:artId:3869](http://tridion.kb.sdl.com/#tab%3ahomeTab%3acrumb:7%3aartId:3869)

Comment: Thank you for response. You said that problem shows on the Publisher side (because the Transport server cannot move the file). Could you please confirm is it related to CM side. The problem occurs on only one Publication target.

Comment: The links above no longer work for me, but this one for web 8.5 does:
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-D4E58EF7-DA59-4538-A0FC-349DA0319ED6